# Como ler arquivos com acentos no Android?

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou tendo problemas para ler arquivos com acentos no Android.

Estou usando o seguinte método para realizar a leitura:

```
public String lerAquivo(File arquivo) {
    String texto;
    String linha;
    BufferedReader br;

    try {
        texto = "";
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo));

        while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!texto.equals("")) {
                texto += "\n";
            }

            texto += linha;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        texto = "";
    }

    return texto;
}
```

Ele está funcionando, mas com um problema. Para alguns arquivos que contém acentos e caracteres especiais esses caracteres não são lidos corretamente.
Alguém sabe a solução?

Sei que provavelmente tem a ver com o encoding. Pesquisei e vi que teria de setar o encoding do arquivo na hora de ler. Mas se realmente for isso como faço pra descobrir o encoding do arquivo?

Comment: O nome do arquivo ou o conteúdo que tem acentos?

Comment: O conteúdo tem acentos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de um bom tempo pesquisando consegui resolver o problema.

O problema era o encoding do arquivo, o FileReader por default usa o encoding padrão do sistema operacional, no caso do Android UTF-8. Quando o arquivo não vinha em UTF-8 os acentos eram perdidos.

Pesquisando bastante encontrei uma biblioteca (que acredito ser do pessoal da Mozilla), a [Juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/). Essa biblioteca consegue **na maioria dos casos** determinar em qual encoding o arquivo foi salvo. Digo na maioria dos casos, pois pelo que pesquisei, nem sempre ela consegue identificar o encoding e ainda quando identifica, nem sempre ela acerta. Eu testei para uns 20 arquivos criados em SOs diferentes e programas diferentes, **ela acertou todas as vezes**, então estou bem satisfeito com esse "na maioria das vezes".

Para adicionar a biblioteca no projeto Android basta importar ela nas dependências do Gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.googlecode.juniversalchardet', name: 'juniversalchardet', version: '1.0.3'
```

Aqui vale um parentese, a Juniversalchardet é uma biblioteca Java, logo você pode baixar o JAR dela ou adicioná-la do repositório [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3).

O método que realiza a leitura do arquivo passa a ler de acordo com o encoding identificado pelo método **getEncoding()**:

```
public String lerAquivo(File arquivo) {
    String texto;
    String linha;
    BufferedReader br;

    try {
        texto = "";
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(arquivo), getEncoding(arquivo)));

        while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!texto.equals("")) {
                texto += "\n";
            }

            texto += linha;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        texto = "";
    }

    return texto;
}
```

E por fim o método getEncoding(), que identifica em qual encoding um arquivo foi gravado:

```
private String getEncoding(File arquivo) {
    UniversalDetector detector;
    String encoding;
    byte[] buf;
    java.io.FileInputStream fis;
    int nread;

    try {
        buf = new byte[4096];
        fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(arquivo);
        detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

        while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
            detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
        }

        detector.dataEnd();

        encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();

        if (encoding == null) {
            encoding = "UTF-8";
        }

        detector.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

    return encoding;
}
```

Note que, caso o encoding não seja encontrado defini o UTF-8 como padrão, pois no meu caso ler sem acentos é melhor que não ler nada.